# Где найти iso образ Android os для устройств с архитектурой ARM?

Tags: android, arm

Использую ноутбук на процессоре ARMv7 и планирую установить android os. На данный момент нашел х86 версию Android, но не ARM, хотя во многих мобильных устройствах стоит именно arm.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

насколько я знаю, iso-образы *google* не распространяет.

а желающим собрать систему из исходников, для «заливки» собранного образа предлагается [интерфейс adb](https://source.android.com/source/building.html#flash-a-device), который подразумевает наличие **уже** установленной на целевом устройстве системы *dalvik/linux* (нынче *art/linux*) aka *android*.

да и, например, с тем же [cyanogenmod](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/CyanogenMod_Installer), насколько мне известно, ровно та же картина.